# How can I test a constant value with mocha, chai, sinon?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, sinon, sinon-chai

to everyone, that's my first time here so I hope to do all in the right way.
So, I'm writing unit tests for my app and `nyc` tell me that I have a file that is not 100% tested, that's a simple file to set the environment to load, and I don't know how can i test it. The file is the following:

```js
const env = ["dev", "stag", "prod"].includes(Process.env?.MODE)? Process.env.MODE: "dev"

module.exports = require(`../config/.${env}.js`);
```

I suppose that I have to test the `includes` but I don't know how I can do it.

I have tried to use `Array.prototype` and `includes` with the sinon.stub but of course I don't know how to "call" the file. Maybe I have to use `spy` but I never use it and I didn't find someone with my same problem, so I suppose that's a stupid question but i want to solve it

Comment: I think you could stub `process.env.MODE` to a value (e.g. `"stag"` and `"no_match"`) and then spy on `require()` and ensure it's being called with the expected path (based on `MODE`).

Comment: I'm sorry, I haven't been able to implement it, I can't tell you if it works or not, if you can send to me a snippet about it I'll test